# MVC call Html.Action within area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an AREA called "Admin"

It uses the same layout page as the rest of my site.
In the layout page I have

```
 @Html.Action("MyMethod", "MyController", null)
```

MyController is **not** in the Admin area but at the root/controllers folder
when I go to any page in side the AREA I get the following execption

**"The controller for path '/admin/home' was not found or does not implement IController"**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@Html.Action("MyMethod", "MyController", new { area = "" })
```